# Matlab2Tikz FaceColor Surfplot

Tags: pgfplots, color, matlab2tikz

I would like to export a surf plot, whose face color is for example green, out of MATLAB R2014a to latex with the aid of matlab2tikz. Unfortunately when i run pdflatex the face color now ranges from red to blue and is not green any more. Is there maybe a possible workaround?

my MATLAB Code:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.5:10);
Z = sin(sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps)./(sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps);
surf(X,Y,Z,'FaceColor','green','EdgeColor','black')
matlab2tikz('face.tikz', 'height', '\figureheight', 'width', '\figurewidth');
```

my Latex Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{8cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{12cm}
\input{face.tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance

Stefan

**EDIT:**

MATLAB produces:
[image: MATLAB]

Matlab2TikZ produces: 
[image: Matlab2TikZ]

Sorry, I first thought I could solve my problem, if someone can solve the "simple" problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you search for a constant color for the faces, right?

In this case, you can provide the `fill` color using `fill=green` or just `green` and edges can be configured by means of `faceted color=black`.

Here is an example which is independent of your file (since I do not have `face.tikz`). The necessary changes can be added to your file, however:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    %scaled ticks=false,
]
\addplot3[surf,green,faceted color=black,samples at={-10,-9.5,...,10}]
    {sin(deg(sqrt(x^2 + y^2) + 1e-10))/(deg(sqrt(x^2 + y^2) + 1e-10))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` to fix the compatibility level to some recent revision (1.9 should also do it if you have an older TeX).

Once you integrate it into your .tex file, you should seriously consider to write `\newlength...` into the preamble, i.e. before `\begin{document}`. Otherwise you will leak memory (TeX is quite bad at it). Only place `\setlength` into your figures.

If you decide that a single face color is not what you want, you can use a `colormap` for the face color combined with `faceted color=black`, perhaps as in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colormap={greenblack}{gray=(0.3) color=(green)},
]

\addplot3[surf,faceted color=black,samples at={-10,-9.5,...,10}]
    {sin(deg(sqrt(x^2 + y^2) + 1e-10))/(deg(sqrt(x^2 + y^2) + 1e-10))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A color map maps the smallest Z value to the first color in the map and the largest Z value to the largest color in the map. There can be many colors in a color map, these will participate as well. The medium Z value will be mapped to the color in the middle (linear interpolation).

Comment: You are absolutely right.

If I add `green` and `faceted color=black` to my tikz file everthing works well and looks really, really nice.

I actually have added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` and written `\newlength...` into the preamble of my "real" document.

Unfortunately I have also "real" problem. Instead of that nice function I only have some points somewhere in the space. I already make use of a colormap for the green/red plane as you can see in the picture in my first edited post. The problem right now is, that the turquoise plane also uses this colormap, instead of using the `FaceColor`.

Comment: That is good to hear. In order to address the remaining problems, I would suggest to add the contents of `face.tikz` file. This would complete the minimal example - without it, it is hard to identify the root cause (this is generally good practise and avoids guessing a unnecessary work)

Answer (score 0):

To add the contents of `face.tikz` file, respectively taking a closer look at this file was the perfect suggestion. I should have thought of that before asking the second time. Sorry for that...

There are two `\addplot3` commands.

```
\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=faceted,
draw=black,
z buffer=sort,
colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(1,0,0); rgb(1pt)=(0,1,0)},
point meta=explicit,
mesh/rows=70]
table[row sep=crcr,header=false,meta index=3] {%
%
-0.254193271955138  4.792   0.581426160480253   0\\
...
-0.257911289045355  4.793   0.579837400860877   1\\
...
\addplot3[%
surf,
opacity=0.5,
shader=faceted interp,
colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(1,0,0); rgb(1pt)=(0,1,0)},
mesh/rows=10]
table[row sep=crcr,header=false] {%
%
-0.25   4.793   0.565534283150811\\
-0.25   4.79416666666667    0.552986932032553\\ ...
```

All I had to do was to replace these lines

```
shader=faceted interp,
colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(1,0,0); rgb(1pt)=(0,1,0)},
```

in the second `\addplot3` command by those

```
green,
faceted color=black,
```

Thanks very very much Christian Feuersänger for your help!